# Case statement in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, triggers, case, conditional-statements

**Please solve my query**

```
create trigger DeleteProduct
Before delete on Product
BEGIN
    select CASE WHEN ((SELECT Inventory.InventoryID FROM Inventory WHERE Inventory.ProductID = OLD.ProductID and Inventory.Quantity=0) ISNULL)
    THEN    
           RAISE(ABORT,'Error code 82')
    Else   
          DELETE from inventory where inventory.ProductID=OLD.ProductID;
    END;

END;
```

**ERROR in near Delete Statement**

Comment: are you sure you need this trigger?  could you get the desired behavior with a `on delete cascade` in the foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put a statement like `DELETE` into an expression like `CASE`.

In the general case, you can make triggers conditional by using the [WHEN clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteProductError
BEFORE DELETE ON Product
WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT InventoryID
                 FROM Inventory
                 WHERE ProductID = OLD.ProductID
                   AND Quantity = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Error code 82');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteProduct
BEFORE DELETE ON Product
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT InventoryID
             FROM Inventory
             WHERE ProductID = OLD.ProductID
               AND Quantity = 0)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Inventory
    WHERE ProductID = OLD.ProductID;
END;
```

Comment: this answer solve my problem. but i want if else with queries. ex if fire delete query else if fire update query else fire delete query..

Comment: SQLite has no if/else. It might be possible to construct a clever sequence of statements that does what you want (see LS_dev's answeer), often by using complex `WHERE` conditions, but SQLite is an embedded database and not designed to do things that could be done easier in the host programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteProduct
BEFORE DELETE ON Product
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT Inventory.InventoryID FROM Inventory WHERE Inventory.ProductID = OLD.ProductID and Inventory.Quantity=0) IS NULL
    THEN RAISE(ABORT,'Error code 82')
    END;
    -- If RAISE was called, next isntructions are not executed.
    DELETE from inventory where inventory.ProductID=OLD.ProductID;
END;
```